# Content Security Policy problems in calling functions and display images

Tags: javascript, onload, content-security-policy

Do not understand the the effect of the policy I specify at my site http://pcrypt.org/dev/groups.php.

```
header("X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self'; img-src *; script-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; style-src 'self';");
```

If I disallow inline scripts how do I then call a function. In the page I have tried to call a function located in a js file on the server from onload (body onload='initialize()') but it generate this error (sorry in Danish):

```
Advarsel: CSP: Directive "inline script base restriction" violated
Kildefil: http://pcrypt.dk/dev/groups.php
Linje: 0
Kildekode:
onload attribute on UNKNOWN element
```

Works fine with `"options inline-script;"` added

Also like to call `initialize()` when the DOM is ready and not wait for images to load but how do I do this with CSP in place?

Also think that I need `"img-src *;"` but then no images are show at all. The images are located on the same server?

Please help me to understand.

Comment: If you want to use your real name, change your username, don't put an extra line in posts. :)

Comment: It is worth noting that the `options` parameter is a Mozilla/Firefox specific and is not defined in W3C spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK now I think I got it ;-)

img-src 'self'; does work now as expected - think I was missing ''

It is impossible to call any sort of functions in the HTML part when CSP is in place. I have to assign onclick event handlers etc. in javascript code. I believed it was possible to call a JS function from the HTML part - this is not the case.

Quite a bit of work to support CSP actually!